# object and var difference in C#

Tags: c#, variables, object, var

What is the difference between `object` and `var`?

Answer (score 7):

- [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) - Not specifying the type explicitly. Letting compiler figure out what that type is.

  - Type is fixed at design time and cannot refer to object of other type.
  - As `Pauli` noted in a comment, you get `intelliSense`.
  - Must be initialized. `var i;` won't compile.
  - Cannot be used as return type of a method.
  - Must be a local variable. Not a field or property.
  - Works great with [`Anonymous Types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). You get `intelliSense`.
- `object` - `System.Object`.

  - Can be used to refer any type at runtime.
  - Here you don't get `intelliSense`.

### Example:

```
var i = 0; // i is of type `System.Int32`.  Same as "int i = 0;"
i = "Some String"; // Compile time error.

object o = 0;  
o = "Some String"; // Works
```

Answer (score 1):

- object will be determined in
     runtime, but var determined in
     compile time.

for example:

```
var i = 2;
object j = 2;
```

and you look at it in ildasm:

```
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0004:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0009:  stloc.1
```

You can see object item should be boxed and var item no need to boxing.

MSDN for [object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

- Also you can do:

  ```
     object i;
     i = 2;
  ```

  but you can't do:

  ```
     var i;
     i = 2;
  ```

  you will get compile error.
- Object is type which all things in
  .Net inherited from it, so you can do
  object x = y for any type of y
  because of inheritance, but var is a
  keyword for implicit type definition,
  for example var i = 2 means int i =
  2.

Comment: you can access members directly on a var based on the type the compiler determines it to be... on object you're stuck with nothing

Comment: The text "object will be determined in runtime" is not true (it is what it is, you may need to perform casts/coercions to work with it). The static type of j is `object` and the static type of i is `int`. In this particular case `object j` will "lift" 2 into an object implicitly (all objects are "reference types"), but imagine the truly identical statements: `var i = (object)2; object j = 2`. In this case, the *run-time type and information is identical*. To be more precise, in: `var s = ""; object s2 = "";` the *object type is identical* -- the difference is the *compile-time/static type*.

Comment: @pst, I added Ildasm to clarify what I said, always there is a boxing and unboxing Issue with this, I said this for that, and I think @Pauli Østerø, said better than mine my first paragraph.

Comment: one thing to keep in mind also with var is that type type will LITERALLY be the type returned by whatever assignment you make. That means that this code will fail: *var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(i => i); list = list.ToList();* why? because var here will be resolved to IOrderedEnumerable and later you're trying to assign IList to it. If you had explicitly set list to be an IEnumerable from the start everything works fine.