# When should I use "var" instead of "object"?

Tags: c#, syntax, var

I was wondering when should you use `var`?

Almost anything in C#, except for maybe the primitives and a few more odd cases, derive from Object.

So wouldn't it be a better practice to use that actual types ? or at least `object` ?

(I've been programming for a while, and my strict point of view is that `var` is evil)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552881/difference-between-var-and-object-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221175/var-vs-object-in-c

Comment: var isn't *evil*, var is **awesome**.  Three little letters keep you from having to type `ObservableCollection<AGiantClassNameThatHasAGenericType<AnotherReallyLongName>>>` *twice* when you create one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487311/object-and-var-difference-in-c

Comment: The var from the old Visual Basic days is not in any way the same as the .NET C# var. The latter is always strongly typed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You misunderstand: `var` isn’t a type. `var` instructs the compiler to use the *correct* type for a variable, based on its initialisation.

Example:

```
var s = "hello";         // s is of type string
var i = 42;              // i is of type int
var x = new [] { 43.3 }; // x is of type double[]
var y = new Foo();       // y is of type Foo
```

Your variables are still strongly typed when using `var`.

As a consequence, `var` isn’t “evil”. On the contrary, it’s very handy and as I’ve said [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c/41514#41514), I use it extensively. Eric Lippert, one of the main people behind C#, has also written [in great detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing.aspx) about whether `var` is bad practice. In a nutshell, “no”.

Comment: Is it bad practise to use `var` for everything?  Why would you use `var` over explicit type casting?

Comment: @Tom We have multiple threads about this. The usage is highly controversial but I don’t really understand the problem. I use it almost everywhere, unless (very rarely!) when readability would suffer from it.

Comment: @Tom: You would explicitly specify the type when doing so makes the code clearer.  Also, in a few rare cases, the compiler cannot infer the type, so you must specify it.

Comment: I know that, I meant "when declaring the variables type", wouldn't it be considered bad pracitce ?

Comment: @Yochai: Why would it? It's a matter of coding style. In most cases the type is either obvious, or of not much interest to the person reading your code. `MyType type = new MyType();` Why say it twice?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: That's trivial, but what about: `SomeType hello = SomeWeirdMethodSomeOtherCompanyWrote()` ... Just as a matter of maintainability, when reviewing the code in the future, the type here is important

Comment: @Yochai: So write it that way. In that context, it's clearer if you specify the type. But I get wiggy when people start using the term "bad practice." It implies that there is only "one right way" to do things, and there seldom is.

Comment: @Yochai What Robert said. But additionally: are you actually sure that the type is important? Because usually it isn’t (Eric Lippert goes into more detail here). If it were, then using interfaces would be a major design issue, and yet the best practice is to use interfaces instead of concrete types pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Again, types are not important if you know what you're doing. Scripting languages work great too, without type declarations. But the benefit of using type names is for maintainability... Sure you know what you're doing, but will another programmer 2 months from now, look at the code and still understand it ? The type says a lot in these cases.

Comment: @Yochai: Well said. When the type is not obvious from the context, specify it explicitly, if doing so improves readability. Otherwise, using `var` is just fine.

Answer (score 9):

You're conflating `var` with `dynamic`, I think. Using `var` is **exactly the same*** as if you had written out the entire type name, and the compiler renders them into the same code. Eric Lippert's blog offers some excellent information on what the `var` keyword does and when to use it.

From Eric Lippert's article **[Uses and misuses of implicit typing:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ericlippert/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing)**

> Summing up, my advice is:
>
> - Use var when you have to; when you are using anonymous types.
> - Use var when the type of the declaration is obvious from the
>     initializer, especially if it is an
>     object creation. This eliminates
>     redundancy.
> - Consider using var if the code emphasizes the semantic "business
>     purpose" of the variable and downplays
>     the "mechanical" details of its
>     storage.
> - Use explicit types if doing so is necessary for the code to be correctly
>     understood and maintained.
> - Use descriptive variable names regardless of whether you use "var".
>     Variable names should represent the
>     semantics of the variable, not details
>     of its storage; "decimalRate" is bad;
>     "interestRate" is good.

*Some might take issue with my "exactly the same" statement. It isn't strictly true for anonymous types, but that's  because you *can't* legally write out the type name.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ericlippert/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing

Comment: @Arwin - Updated the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Using `object` you'd lose all static type information (and when used on a value type it even causes boxing). So using `object` is very different from using `var`.

`var` on the other hand is equivalent to using the actual(static) type. So you use it when stating the actual type is either impossible or inconvenient.

- One scenario where `var` is necessary is when using anonymous types. They have no name(nitpick: only a compiler generated name that you don't know), so you can't name the type explicitly.
- One case where using `var` is convenient is when you're typename is very long. This happens sometimes when using nested generics.
- And in `foreach` loops you avoid the unsafe implicit cast.

Answer (score 4):

`var` and `object` are two entirely different things.

With `var`, the compiler is inferring the type for you. An `object` is an object, and you lose any information you had about the instance since C# is a strongly typed language.

See section 26.1 from the C# specification:

> In an implicitly typed local variable declaration, the type of the local variable being declared is inferred from
>   the expression used to initialize the variable. When a local variable declaration specifies var as the type and no
>   type named var is in scope, the declaration is an implicitly typed local variable declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Your "strict point of view" is a little misinformed... `var` DOES use the actual type. The compiler analyzes the return type of the expression on the right hand side and uses that as the type of the assignment.

Comment: I never doubted the compiler, I just wandered if it's a good programming practice

Comment: I would say it is only a *really* good practice if the type is basically understood, but really long to type out. (It really helps in using LINQ to Objects, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

`var` is not a type. `var` says to the compiler 'I'm not sure/can't be bothered typing the proper type name here, please infer the type for me based on the context of this statement'.

`Object` casts the object to type `Object`. As a result you lose any type information, so can no longer call specific methods, access properties etc that are defined at a level lower in the hierarchy than `Object`.